# jQuery, image loading events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm building a jQuery Plugin to turn a div full of `<img />` into a gallery. I ran into a problem, i can't seem to solve:
right now, i call the plugin on document ready so, for a few 10ths of a second, i can see all the images at the same time, before i hide() all but the first one.

the plugin works this way:

```
$(function(){$('div').gallery();});
```

and in the plugin:

```
$(this).find('img').wrap('<div />').hide();
$(this).find('img:first').show();
```

does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have no control over when the user
>   of your plugin calls it.

He/she may delay calling it for seconds or minutes after the page has loaded along with all the images. So it is up to him/her to hide the images e.g. via CSS: `{display: none}`.

Comment: well, that's well pointed, i can ask them to hide the images. But that leaves me with a problem, i use the width and height of the first image to calculate everything regarding the gallery. and if the images are all display none, i have to delay the begining of those calculations...

Comment: well, i guess this is it, what i was saying isn't a problem at all. Thank u

Answer (score 2):

If I want to hide stuff for browsers that support js I find that the best way is to

```
<body>
  <script>document.body.className = "js";</script>
```

Then you could just hide stuff in your css

```
body.js .mygalleryimagesdiv {
  display: none;
}
```

And show them when you're ready in the script...
This is the only non unobtrusive script i allow myself to write :)

Comment: yes, that would work. but i'm trying to build a plugin that is the most generic possible, for someone just needing to invoke it onready, i don't want them to hack their way to the body

Comment: I think you'll have to deal with the fact that the browser renders from top to bottom :)

Comment: damn posting on enter...   what i meant to add is that many jquery plugins twitches a little in the setup-phase.   You could supply some optional css to make the experience better where you always hide divs with the class of your choice.

Comment: Simply _document_ the fact that the plugin initially needs to be hidden via CSS and you've done your job (grin :)

Answer (score 1):

You should initially hide the images preferably via CSS or by using inline styles. You can then show them via jQuery.show() or jQuery.css() methods.